# Ubuntuone for backup

Tags: ubuntu-one, backup

I want to use Ubuntuone as backup for two machines (one a server and one a desktop). I have the desktop sync'd, but if I add the server in it loads the desktop files to the server.

Any suggestions as to how I can keep the two of them separate?

Answer (score 2):

Get two accounts.

Also, please read [Ubuntu One: can this be used for backups?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37234/ubuntu-one-can-this-be-used-for-backups).